# How to add a custom HTML element in Firefox? (Chrome works)

Tags: javascript, html, class, google-chrome, firefox

I'm exploring Vanilla ES6 Javascript. And it would be nice to use custom HTML elements.

I add a custom HTML element defined as HTMLElement class using

```
customElements.define('my-div', myDiv);
```

Then I create an element with it and add it to the DOM.

```
const elem = document.getElementById('test');
const myDiv = document.createElement('my-div'); 
elem.insertBefore(myDiv, null);
```

This works fine with Chrome, but not with Firefox. But it is marked as experimental there, so it might come.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/lafisrap/pen/jGWELp?editors=1010)

```js
class myDiv extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = '<div>Hello custom HTML element!</div>';
  }
}

customElements.define('my-div', myDiv);

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const elem = document.getElementById('test');
  const myDiv = document.createElement('my-div');
  
  elem.insertBefore(myDiv, null);
});
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

how can I use this now, without using a library like babel?
(Preferably also for Safari and Edge)

Comment: See: https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to enable `dom.webcomponents.shadowdom.enabled` and `dom.webcomponents.customelements.enabled` in `about:config`. Works ok in FF 60.